# passing parameters beetween controllers with shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, parameter-passing, segue

i'm trying to perform a `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and pass some parameters between controllers.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"myid" ]) {
        return NO;

    }

    mydestviewcontroller* my = [segue destinationviewcontroller];
    my.stringtopass= data;



    return YES;


}
}
```

I get an error on the segue of `[segue destinationviewcontroller]`
instead if I use prepare for segue it doesn't show.
I need to perform some checks before the segue to happen and if it happens I need to pass parameters to the destination controller. Help me out folks!!

Comment: Where is defined `segue`?

Comment: I don't know i just use standard functions of ios.

Answer (score 2):

Passing some parameters between controllers use `prepareForSegue`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifer isEqualToString:"myId"]) {
        mydestviewcontroller* my = [segue destinationViewController];
        my.stringtopass= data;

}
```

Comment: i need to perform a check, if condition is not verified no segue takes place, otherwise it takes place and the parameters are passed.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the check inside `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and then pass the data inside `prepareForSegue`. `prepareForSegue` will only be executed if you return `YES` in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: i tried this at first but it doesn't prevent the segue to happen when the check takes action

Comment: did you make sure there are no errors in the checks? put NSLogs/Breakpoints and check what is being returned.

Comment: hi, sorry. In the shouldperform i do a get request and memorize the obtained parameter in a public Nsstring, then when in the prepareforsegue i try to pass the parameter it gets null.

Comment: If this helps, press the green tick to accept this answer.